# How can i add linq query EnumerableRowCollection<TRow> to a datatable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `linq` query:

```
 var lastDaysData = from myRow in rawDataSet.AsEnumerable()
                            where myRow.Field<DateTime>("DateTime") < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)
                            select myRow;
```

which i think should return the last 24 hrs worth of data from the SQL database.

i am trying to add the results of the query to a `datatable` with a `foreach` loop:

```
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataRow row in lastDaysData)
            {
                dataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

However, my `datagridview` is not populating with any data.

So am i adding the rows incorrectly to the `datatable` or is my linq query wrong?

Comment: Please check if your query returns any records. Looks like your query is wrong, because it returns records older than 24h, instead of last 24h.

Comment: What does debugger say when you put break inside loop?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Mabye you swallow exception in an empty catch

Comment: _"should return the last 24 hrs worth of data from the SQL database"_ Well, since a `DataTable` is an in-memory collection it is not linked to a sql-database. Maybe you think it would query the rows from database, but that is not the case. You need a `SqlDataAdapter` then.

Comment: @Wokuo ahha, i wasnt sure if that was the case, but even so there is lots of data older than 24hrs so it should still return data. I will check

Comment: Neither.  The DGV is not getting repainted.  You would get an exception if it wasn't working.  The trick is to set the datasource to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for `ImportRow` is poor - what it should make clear is that fields from the row to be imported are copied to matching fields in the destination `DataTable`, so since your `DataTable` has no columns, there is nothing to copy in.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, I would say you shouldn't use `DataTable`s in modern C#, you should use EF or LINQ to SQL and use objects directly.

But when I must work with them, I use some extension methods to make using LINQ with `DataTable`s a bit easier.

This one converts the resulting `IEnumerable<DataRow>` from a LINQ query on a `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` back to a `DataTable` with a matching schema:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<DataRow> src) {
    var ans = src.First().Table.Clone();
    foreach (var r in src)
        ans.ImportRow(r);
    return ans;
}
```

This one let's you use anonymous objects to select out columns and then creates a new `DataTable` from the objects, but it uses reflection and so can be slow. It may be better to make a variation of the above `ToDataTable` that takes a list of column names projects the answer accordingly.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if (rows.Any()) {
        var rowType = typeof(T);
        var memberInfos = rowType.GetPropertiesOrFields();
        foreach (var info in memberInfos)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.GetMemberType()));

        foreach (var r in rows)
            dt.Rows.Add(memberInfos.Select(i => i.GetValue(r)).ToArray());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

You need some `MemberInfo` extensions to make working with properties and fields easier:

```
// ***
// *** Type Extensions
// ***
public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

// ***
// *** MemberInfo Extensions
// ***
public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.FieldType;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.PropertyType;
        case EventInfo mei:
            return mei.EventHandlerType;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}

public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);
```

Finally, if you do a join across multiple `DataTable`s, you can flatten the answer back to another `DataTable` with this method:

```
// Create new DataTable from LINQ results on DataTable
// Expect T to be anonymous object of form new { DataRow d1, DataRow d2, ... }
public static DataTable FlattenToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) {
    var res = new DataTable();
    if (src.Any()) {
        var firstRow = src.First();
        var rowType = typeof(T);
        var memberInfos = rowType.GetPropertiesOrFields();
        var allDC = memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => mi.GetValue<DataRow>(firstRow).Table.DataColumns());

        foreach (var dc in allDC) {
            var newColumnName = dc.ColumnName;
            if (res.ColumnNames().Contains(newColumnName)) {
                var suffixNumber = 1;
                while (res.ColumnNames().Contains($"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}"))
                    ++suffixNumber;
                newColumnName = $"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}";
            }
            res.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(newColumnName, dc.DataType));
        }

        foreach (var objRows in src)
            res.Rows.Add(memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => mi.GetValue<DataRow>(objRows).ItemArray).ToArray());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for Flatten. I am not sure what this procedure does. Thanks

Comment: @kuklei If you use LINQ to do a join of two `DataTables`, it will convert the anonymous object holding the `DataRow`s from the separate tables into one new `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself in the end.

I had to add the columns i wanted to a `List` first, then add the list to a `dataTable`

```
     var rawDataSet = pDCDataSet.RawData;

        var lastDaysData = from myRow in rawDataSet.AsEnumerable()
                           where myRow.Field<DateTime>("DateTime") > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text))
                           select new
                           {
                               myRow.DateTime,
                               myRow.FolderSize,
                               myRow.FileNumber,
                               //myRow.Results,
                           };

       var newlist = lastDaysData.ToList();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("DateTime");
        dt.Columns.Add("FolderSize");
        dt.Columns.Add("FileNumber");
        foreach (var item in newlist)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            row["DateTime"] = item.DateTime;
            row["FolderSize"] = Convert.ToString(item.FolderSize);
            row["FileNumber"] = item.FileNumber;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }


        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: There is no benefit to using `ToList` with `newlist` - you should just loop over `lastDaysData` (`foreach (var item in lastDaysData)`) - you are just wasting memory and time building a `List` you immediately enumerate.